# Default pathfinding system in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need a pathfinding system for a shooter game I'm making. I know that there a lot of plugins available for pathfinding in unity. I was just wondering if unity has a built in pathfinding system ?

Comment: This question belongs to GD.SE. In fact it is already cross-posted there: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/82481/does-unity-have-a-built-in-pathfinding-system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working on a 3D game there is a built in pathfinding system using `NavMeshAgent`.  You will need to use `NavMesh` for your terrain. Use it like this:

```
NavMeshAgent agent;
agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
agent.SetDestination (hit.point);
```

where `hit.point` is the point where player clicks. There's a live training archive on this subject, [here](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/navmeshes) on unity3d official website.

However if you're working on a 2D game, currently there is none, but it will be coming in one day, as stated [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/can-2d-games-use-the-navigation-mesh.211506/). You will have to search for 2D pathfinding solutions in the asset store for now.